# Difference between "stir up" and "provoke"

Tags: differences

Just I want to know the difference between the "stir up" and "provoke", where it should be placed exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting.

Well, to *stir up* means to instigate, or initiate or to set in motion. So a sample sentence could be

> Che stirred up a revolution against oppression.

To *provoke* is to stimulate or give rise to a strong emotion or a reaction, which is typically an unwelcome one. A sample sentence could be

> Che provoked the masses to set all the houses on fire.

Does that clear your doubts?

Comment: Yes Dear n0nChun, It is very clear and useful.

Answer (score 1):

In this sense *provoke* is about creating a reaction

> He provoked the crowd by telling them what their enemies would do

while *stir up* is used to mean excite

> He stirred up the crowd by telling them how strong they were

*Stir up* is in common English usage because of a phrase in the old Anglican collect for the [last Sunday before Advent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stir-up_Sunday)

> Stir up, we beseech thee, O Lord, the wills of thy faithful people

where it was a translation of the Latin *excita*. It was taken as an indicator that it was  time to make (i.e. stir up) Christmas puddings.

Answer (score 0):

*Provoke* means "stimulate or give rise to a reaction or emotion (typically a strong or unwelcome one) in someone," while *stir up* means "arouse strong feeling in (someone); move or excite.

> The decision provoked a storm of protest from civil rights organizations.
>   She stirred up the sweating crowd.

The difference is that *provoke* is also used for an unwelcome reaction or emotion, while *stir up* is used for a strong feeling.